# Sequelize query within belongsToMany relations

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to figure out how to query relations in Sequelize. Let's say I have a `UserModel` and an `IssueModel`, and they each have a `belongsToMany` relation with each other. I want a query to this effect:

```
SELECT
    ...,
    (
        EXISTS(
            SELECT 1
            FROM user_issues
            WHERE user_issues.user_id = <some_id>
                AND user_issues.issue_id = issue.id
        )
    ) AS isSubscribed
```

The only stuff I've been able to find in the docs about relations is the `include` option, but nothing on this sort of calculated member

Comment: All I can think for now is [`countAssociations`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/belongs-to-many/#countassociationsoptions-promiseint) method of `belongsToMany` relation. In such a case it would be `user.countIssues()`

Comment: That's close, but it would require a separate query. Not the end of the world, but doesn't scale well when getting multiple issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following

```
User.findAll({
  attributes: ['User.*', 'Issue.*', [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('Issue.id')), 'PostCount']],
  include: [Issue]
}
```

Comment: This is kind of backwards; what I'm looking for is a boolean on the Issue determining if a particular user is mapped to it, not a count of issues mapped to the user.